# Set value to Field collection item link field

Tags: 8, entities

I have a Field Collection item which consist of a drop down, a text box and a link field. After the user submits a form I create a node were this field collection item is included. Before I save it, I populate some fields.

I managed to set the 'Url' in the link field(part of field collection item) by using:

```
$field_collection_item2->field_url->setValue($base_url . '/form/email-project-completion-survey');
```

Which works fine. Now I'm trying to set the 'Link text' but I can't make it work.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it by using an array in setValue.

```
$field_collection_item2->field_url->setValue(array('uri'=>$base_url . '/form/email-project-completion-survey', 'title' => 'Survey'));
```